# How to sort Arraylist of LinkedHashMap Arraylist<LinkedHashMap<String,String>?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, hashmap, linkedhashmap

How can i sort Arraylist of LinkedHashMap
Ex.

```
ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>();
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        linkedHashMap.put("city", "AB");
        linkedHashMap.put("name", "N");
        linkedHashMap.put("area", "xyz");
        list.add(linkedHashMap);
        linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        linkedHashMap.put("city", "BA");
        linkedHashMap.put("name", "AB");
        linkedHashMap.put("area", "xyz");
        list.add(linkedHashMap);
        linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        linkedHashMap.put("city", "CH");
        linkedHashMap.put("name", "AB");
        linkedHashMap.put("area", "PQ");
        list.add(linkedHashMap);
```

Above is my ArrayList of LinkedHashMap & i want to Sort Value taking Ref as Key (like Sort By City or Sort by name)
I have Done LinkedHashMap(Without Arraylist) Sorting by using Collection.Sort & comparable . 
But how can i Sort My Arraylist of LinkedHashMap(Using Loop or Iterator it may possible but is there any other simple way?)
Thanks

Comment: ArrayList<T> can be sorted only if T implements Comparable interface. So you need to design a custom LinkedHashMap class implementing Comparable and then use Collections.sort() to sort them.

Comment: I would suggest using entities(pojo) instead of linked hash map of storing your object it help you implement comparator. you can find dozen of links by simple google search 'how to sort ArrayList in java'. hope this will help.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement the `Comparator<T>` and use `Collections.sort` to sort by the particular value of your `LinkedHashMap`

---

However, in you case, you should take advantage of class. Make a class that represent the data in`LinkedHashMap`

```
public class MyClass {
    private String city;
    private String name;
    private String area;

    // implement some getters here.
}
```

Then, again, use `Collections.sort`, and implement the comparator you want

```
List<MyClass> myClasses = getMyClasses();
Collections.sort(myClasses, new Comparator<MyClass>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(MyClass o1, MyClass o2) {
        // implement sorting behavior you want.
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can do as follows:

```
    Collections.sort(list ,
            new Comparator<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>()
            {
                @Override
                public int compare(LinkedHashMap<String, String> obj1,
                        LinkedHashMap<String, String> obj2)
                {
                    return (obj1.get("city").compareTo(obj2.get("city")));
                }
            });
```